# Clang: Output a 32 AND 64 bit combination .dylib

Tags: macos, clang, cpu-architecture, dylib

I've seen dylibs that are both 32 and 64 bit when performed the `file` command on. How do I go about building one in Clang?

The -m32 flag creates 32 bit dylib, -m64 makes 64 bit, but using both of them doesn't work.

Edit: For instance, here's the output of `file` on the type of dylib I'm trying to build

```
file /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL 
/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use the `-arch` argument multiple times for each architecture you want, e.g.

```
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 ...
```

or create multiple binaries, then glue them together with `lipo`:

```
lipo -create -arch i386 my32bitbinary -arch x86_64 my64bitbinary -output myfatbinary
```